# Batch file that searches cmdline output for keyword and displays the previous line(x5)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a batch file that runs a command in the command line and searches the output for a keyword. It then outputs the line previous to the line with the keyword.

For example: Search for KEYWORD

PREVIOUS LINE

KEYWORD

result: PREVIOUS LINE

The code is as follows

```
set Output="pnputil -e"
FOR /F "eol=. tokens=*" %%a IN ( '%Output%' ) DO (
    set line=%%a
    set ourline=!line:KEYWORD=!
    if not !line!==!ourline! (
        SET Output=!prev_line!
    )
    SET prev_line=%%a
)
echo Installed OEM file found as: !Output!
```

I want to replicate this but the line I want is 5 lines previous to the keyword. The output I want is followed by 4 lines of random info with only one constant keyword 5 lines after it that I can search.

Answer (score 0):

There could be used the driver date and version to identify the `oem*.inf` file of an installed driver. The batch file below searches for a driver with the driver date `06/12/2020` and the driver version `16.51.39.165`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName="
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe -e 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%I %%J" == "Published name" (
        set "FileName=%%K"
    ) else if "%%I %%J" == "Driver date" (
        set "DriverDateVersion=%%K"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if not "!DriverDateVersion:06/12/2020 16.51.39.165=!" == "!DriverDateVersion!" echo Installed OEM file found as: !FileName!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
```

But it is of course also possible to remember in the loop the last four lines and check every line for the string to find like `Hardware Compatibility` as done by the batch file below.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Line1=?"
set "Line2=?"
set "Line3=?"
set "Line4=?"
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\pnputil.exe -e 2^>nul') do (
    set "Line1=!Line2!"
    set "Line2=!Line3!"
    set "Line3=!Line4!"
    set "Line4=!CurrentLine!"
    set "CurrentLine=%%I"
    if not "!CurrentLine:Hardware Compatibility=!" == "!CurrentLine!" echo(!Line1!
)
endlocal
```

**Note:** Lines with one or more `!` are not corrected processed by this code because of permanently enabled delayed environment variable expansion which results in interpreting an exclamation mark in the string assigned to loop variable `I` as beginning/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference.

There are lots of other possible solutions depending on the data to process.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pnputil -?` or `pnputil /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

You may easily store the 5 lines previous to the searched one in a very simple way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "eol=. delims=" %%a in ('pnputil -e') do (
   set "i=5"
   for /L %%n in (4,-1,1) do set "line!i!=!line%%n!" & set "i=%%n"
   set "line1=%%a"
   if not "!line1!" == "!line1:KEYWORD=!" set "Output=!line5!"
)

echo Result: %Output%
```

You may change the number of stored lines by changing just 2 lines...